# Force a static street view to be outdoor

Tags: google-street-view

The JS API lets the user decide if the response must be an outdoor view, indoor view or if it doesn't matter.

Can we do the same and ask to get the **outdoor view only** using the static API, for example for the following request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=41.8866638,-87.6314861&heading=151.78